# How to add html page to another html page by using object tag?

Tags: html, object, frame

I found this code. but it is not working...

```
<div id="frame">
     <object type="text/html" data="slider.html"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. What happens in which browser(s)? IE 7 and older default the size to 0×0, so this might be your problem, solvable by setting `width` and `height` attributes for the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Have to set the width and height of `object`

```
<object class="myObject" type="text/html" data="myFile.html"></object>

<style>
.myObject {
   height:500px;
   width:500px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple way to do this, simply what you can do is convert both to asp page and use include tag at position where you want to use the other html.

Alternatively, you can use iframe for it. a iframe can have a different html source file.

Comment: <object> gives a similar result to an <iframe>, it's just a little less intuitive.